# splitting different columns of a file with different delimiter and print only part of it

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited file with following format (multiple columns):

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NORMAL
1   22  .   C   A   .   PASS    aa;bb;cc    ee:ff:rr:dd xx:vv:yy:zz
1   34  .   G   T   .   PASS    aa;bb;cc    ee:ff:rr:dd xx:vv:yy:zz
1   56  .   C   G   .   PASS    aa;bb;cc    ee:ff:rr:dd xx:vv:yy:zz
```

desired output:

```
1   22  C   A   .   zz  vv/yy   cc
1   34  G   T   .   zz  vv/yy   cc
1   56  C   G   .   zz  vv/yy   cc
```

Comment: Where does the `.` (period) come from in your output? It's not the 5th "entry" of column 10; should it always be a period, or is it one of the columns? You might spell out how columns 8 and 10 are split up (by colons and semicolons I assume?). Also, how did you get 0.40 = 51 (3rd entry of 10) / 31 (4th entry of 10)?

Comment: Your sample output does not match your specification.

Comment: If there’s a header, you should include it. You want the mathematical operation of division for vv/yy, correct?! You should spell that out, otherwise people could easily interpret that as vv + “/“ + yy

Comment: No its not the mathematical operation, but sign "/". i have added the headers also. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want using a regex for the field separator. Assuming that `:` and `;` are sub-field separators for fields 9 and 10 in the example you provided, here is an example of how to print out specific fields and sub-fields:

```
$ awk -F'[\t;:]' '{ print $1,$2,$4,$5,$18, $10, $16, $22 }' file
1 1278229 C A . SSC=7 FREQ 40%
```

Your current description of the sub-fields that you what is unclear and your sample output is even more unclear, but you should be able to modify my example to get the output you want.

UPDATE: Based on the final supplied input, the following `awk` command produces the sample output:

```
$ awk -v FS='[\t;:]' -v OFS='\t' 'NR > 1 { print $1, $2, $4, $5, $6, $18, $16"/"$17, $10 }' infile
1   22  C   A   .   zz  vv/yy   cc
1   34  G   T   .   zz  vv/yy   cc
1   56  C   G   .   zz  vv/yy   cc
$
```

Comment: Thanks fpmurphy for the solution. I thought of this, in my case each column has many sub columns (after splitting with respective delimiters) hence it was getting very difficult to count all the columns. I wanted sth where I could only count specific (needed) sub column from each column.